# firestore upload a file : Unsupported field value: a custom File object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload a file in the firestore and the following code is working:

```
 export const ticketEdit = values => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    // delete file
    const file = values.file && values.file;
    delete values.file;

    try {
      // uploadFile
      if (file) await dispatch(ticketUploadFile(file, ticketId));

      // notification
      toastr.success(i18n.t("Success", i18n.t("The ticket is updated")));

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
```

However, If I will put the lines that I am deleting the file

```
// delete file
const file = values.file && values.file;
delete values.file;
```

In the try catch statement like this :

```
 export const ticketEdit = values => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    try {
      // delete file
      const file = values.file && values.file;
      delete values.file;
      if (file) await dispatch(ticketUploadFile(file, ticketId));

      // notification
      toastr.success(i18n.t("Success", i18n.t("The ticket is updated")));

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
```

I get the error

> Unsupported field value: a custom File object.

and I would like to know why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the try catch statement but that I was trying to update the values before deleting the file.

Lesson learned: delete the files before updating the document.